# py --version: Access is denied if not admin in command prompt

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

When I run command prompt as Admin, I am able to check my python version (Python 3.7.1). When I'm not admin and check the version of python, I get the message **"Access is denied."**

What is happening here?

```
C:\Users\username>py --version
Access is denied.
```

Comment: What is `py`? The command is usually `python`. If you're using some customized environment, it is unlikely that we will be able to help.

Comment: @GreenMatt https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#getting-started

Comment: @ipaleka: Thanks. I've not used 3 on Windows yet.

Comment: i guess while installing python you have to install it for all users.

Comment: That's a problem with the security on py.exe. Run `where.exe py`. Then run `icacls.exe "path\to\py"` and copy the output into your question.

Comment: @eryksun 

C:\Users\username>where.exe py
C:\Users\username\py.exe
C:\Windows\py.exe

C:\Users\username>icacls.exe "C:\Users\jwfei\py.exe"
C:\Users\usernamei\py.exe NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
                      MSI\username:(F)
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                      MSI\username:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\Users\username>py --version
Access is denied.

Comment: Is "MSI\username" your user on the current system, which is named "MSI"? In that case you'd have full control. Anyway, something is wrong here. There should an inherited (I) entry that grants read and execute (RX) access to "BUILTIN\Users". It's inherited from an entry on "C:\Windows" that grants generic read and execute access (GR, GE) to files (OI) and directories (CI).

Comment: Try fixing this from an administrator command prompt: `icacls C:\Windows\py.exe /grant *BU:(RX)`. "BU" is an alias for "Builtin\Users" (S-1-5-32-545). The alias or SID is preferred because it's not localized, and the asterisk prefix allows specifying users and groups by SID or alias on the icacls command line.

Comment: @eryksun This is admittedly a little over my head. 

C:\Users\username>icacls C:\Windows\py.exe /grant *BU:(RX)
C:\Windows\py.exe: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

Comment: According to your previous comment, administrators should have full control. Make sure you're using an administrator command prompt.  The title at the top of the console window should begin with "Administrator: ".